# jQuery get part of innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I need to get the html of a p tag, however there is a br tag inside of it. So it looks like:

```
<p>
    Some Text
    <br>
    Some More Text
</p>
```

I need to get the first part and second part separately. So I could do something like:

```
$('p').html() //Up To '<'
$('p').html() //After '>'
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Will the content of the paragraph always be just like that?

Comment: did you try:   var arr = $('p').html().split("<br>");  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that there's always going to be a `<br>` tag, then yes.
Otherwise you can utilize regex.

```
var foo = $('p').html().split('<br>')[0];
var bar = $('p').html().split('<br>')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to retrieve the nodes that are present inside,

```
$('p').contents()[0].nodeValue;
$('p').contents()[2].nodeValue;
```

And `node` object has a property called [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue), it will give you the text that you need.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/avpp4gz8/)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two options:

First: Using substring ([FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vbd0sorb/))

```
var content = $('p').html();
var firstPart = content.substring(0,content.indexOf("<br>"));
var secondPart = content.substring(content.indexOf("<br>") + 4,content.length);
```

Second: Using split ([FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vbd0sorb/1/))

```
var content = $('p').html().split("<br>");
var firstPart = content[0];
var secondPart = content[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible!!!
use the split function...

```
$('p').html().split("<br>")[0];
$('p').html().split("<br>")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var str = $('p').html();

   console.log(str.split('<br>'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery split method to split the content at the `<br>` tag. Then grab everything up to that.

```
var text = $('p').html();
text.split('<br>')[0];
text.split('<br>')[1];
```

To get the second part, you use the same split method but grab everything after the 
 tag.

Here is a link to MDN further explaining the split() method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split